# wordpress add_rewrite_rule not rewriting

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added this code to my themes `functions.php` file

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^shop/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=1247&page=$matches[1]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 'top');
```

so when i browse to `domain.com/shop/page1` it should rewrite to `index.php?page_id=1247&page=page1` but when i do the following on `page_id=1247` i get these results

```
echo $_GET["page"]; // = nothing
print_r($_GET) // = `Array( )`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get parameters with `$wp_query->query_vars`

Here is an example

```
global $wp_query;
echo $wp_query->query_vars['id'];
```

**UPDATE**

You need use `add_rewrite_tag`

```
add_rewrite_tag('%id%', '([^&]+)');
```

Also wordpress use `page` in query, so use another name

Comment: ive changed ['id'] to ['page'] which is what is in my rewrite rule but its just returning 0

Comment: test it with `var_dump($wp_query->query_vars)`, also clear cache with saving permalink in admin

Comment: that is coming back as: ["page"]=> int(0)

Comment: @charlie I think wordpress use `page` for internal action. rename `page` to something else, also see my update

Comment: where do i add that tag?

Comment: @charlie in `custom_rewrite_rule` function, change id to new name and clear cache

Answer (score 0):

Have you flushed and regenerated the rewrite rules in the database? As stated by [the docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule#Basic_Usage):

> **IMPORTANT:** Do not forget to flush and regenerate the rewrite rules database after modifying rules. From WordPress Administration Screens, Select Settings -> Permalinks and just click Save Changes without any changes.

Whenever you add a new rewrite rule you need to click "Save Changes" in the Permalinks admin page (even though you're not changing anything in this page) to make sure Wordpress updates the rules in the database.

Comment: @charlie You may try [Rewrite Rules Inspector](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/) plugin.

Comment: okay, i can see the rule there (^shop/([^/]*)/? index.php?page_id=1247&page=$matches[1]) but on the page its still showing Array( ) using print_r and nothing when using echo

Comment: In which file are you trying to debug and `print_r($_GET)`? Wordpress relies on it's [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png) to determine which PHP file will be loaded. So if you're using `print_r` in your `index.php` but you have a `page.php` (or `page-1247.php`) you'll never see anything.

Comment: i have a page in WP (id = 1247), this page has a custom template on it and im doing the print_r and echo in that custom template file